# Solve Location Allocation tool missing

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, network-analyst, location-allocation

I cannot find the Solve Location Allocation tool pane that should be in the Ready to Use Tools.. I have spent 3 hours trying to figure this out and no clues. I have the licensing's for Network Analyst and the ArcGIS Pro 3.1 version.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**The first thing I saw in your screenshot was this highlighted in red below. Is this what you are searching?**

Location allocation tool pane is not a part of ready to use tools in ArcGIS Pro. Also Pro is context driven, so in all cases the tabs depends on the layers added on map + the layers selected in the contents pane.

[https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/get-started/introducing-arcgis-pro.htm#:~:text=Tabs%20on%20the%20ribbon%20change%20depending%20on%20the%20active%20view.%20Within%20a%20view%2C%20different%20contextual%20tabs%20become%20available%20depending%20on%20the%20layer%20or%20data%20you%20are%20working%20with](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/get-started/introducing-arcgis-pro.htm#:%7E:text=Tabs%20on%20the%20ribbon%20change%20depending%20on%20the%20active%20view.%20Within%20a%20view%2C%20different%20contextual%20tabs%20become%20available%20depending%20on%20the%20layer%20or%20data%20you%20are%20working%20with).

[image]

Comment: Yes the parameters are entered through location-allocation ribbon. My assigment was showing me that the place where they are inputted was through a solve location-allocation tool inside the ready to use tools. Perhaps in the past it was like that..